# Can't assign a specific value to a variable

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

We were required to do servlet handling where we needed to compute for the net pay salary of an employee with the inputs given by the user. I managed to get the info right but when it came to getting the rate the output shows 0 instead of the assigned hourly rate that depends on what the position the user inputs. Here's the block of code I have so far:
{

```
private int rate;
private int grosspay;
private int sss;
private double philhealth;
private double pagibig;
private double tax;
private double deductions;

private int bonus;
private double netpay;


public ComputeBean()
{}

public void setEmployeeid(int employeeid)
{
    this.employeeid = employeeid;
}

public int getEmployeeid()
{
    return employeeid;
}

public void setEmployeename(String employeename)
{
    this.employeename = employeename;
}

public String getEmployeename()
{
    return employeename;
}

public void setDepartment(String department)
{
    this.department = department;
}

public String getDepartment()
{
    return department;
}

public void setHour(int hour)
{
    this.hour = hour;
}

public int getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

public void setCategory(String category)
{
    this.category = category;
}

public String getCategory()
{
    return category;
}

public void setPosition(String position)
{
    this.position = position;
}

public String getPosition()
{
    return position;
}

private void setRate(int rate) 
{}

public void computeRate(int rate)
{
    getPosition();

    if(position.equals("clerk"))
    {
        setRate(rate = 100);
    }

    else if(position.equals("sup"))
    {
        setRate(rate = 200);
    }

    else if(position.equals("mana"))
    {
        setRate(rate = 300);
    }

    else if(position.equals("exec"))
    {
        setRate(rate = 500);
    }
}

public int getRate()
{
    return rate;
}
```

}
}

Comment: Side note - [Never use doubles for money](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/330057)

Answer (score 2):

When using a setter, just pass the value, like so

```
else if(position.equals("exec"))
{
    setRate(500);
}
```

Then make sure your setter actually does something!

```
private void setRate(int rate) 
{
    this.rate = rate;
}
```

Comment: still getting 0 for rate

Comment: Are you sure that you called compute rate before displaying the rate information to the screen?

Comment: omg so thats what i was missing hallelujah you are a life saver friend